# Cordova + WKWebView href links won't open unless long press

Tags: cordova, href, wkwebview

I have a Cordova app, using WKWebView.

I have some links, like `<a href='website'></a>`, and they won't open on a regular click.
However, when I long press them, they do work, and are opening in the native iOS inner window.

1. Links with SMS or mailto does work, like `<a href=SMS:000></a>`.
2. I also have InAppBrowser plugin, and when I use it by writing my link as `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('website', '_blank');"></a>` it does open in the InAppBrowser with a regular click, but it looks less nice than the native iOS window.

How can I make my links to open in the native inner window with a simple click?

[image]